# How to calculate the age when substract two dates in dataweave?

Tags: date, dataweave

Does anyone know how to calculate an age  (years, months and days) with the result of a substraction of two dates ?

When sustract I get this : "P23Y11M23D"

thanks

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I use the version 2.0 and Runtime 4.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you got is a Period and you can deconstruct it by asking for years, months and days like this:

```
var period = |P23Y11M23D|
---
{
    year: period.years,
    months: period.months,
    days: period.days
}
```

Also you can get like the total amount in days or months of the period as explained [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-types#period-coercion).